# Optimizing Azure SQL Elastic Pools with high memory but low CPU

Tags: database, azure, memory-management, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

I have a couple General Purpose SQL elastic pools that are configured at 8 vCores. The CPU of these pools peak no higher than 30% which inclines me to want to reconfigure the elastic pool (to maybe 4 vCores). However, the SQL instance memory percent of these pools have peaked as high as 80%. Is there a way for me to optimize these pools? Would increasing allocated storage to the pool help at all?

I have thought about sizing the number of vCores down but I don't want to do this if it there will not be enough memory to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, by design the available RAM for your Azure SQL Databases will be always proportional (a variable that depends on) to the number of vCores of the tier. It is the same for vCore and DTU models, and it is also the same for Azure SQL Managed Instance. You can verify that by querying the sys.dm_user_db_resource_governance dynamic management view when you scale up or down a database. There is no way to avoid that.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_user_db_resource_governance
```

Comment: What is it that is actually using up memory? Some other pools are configured the same but their CPU and memory were low enough to allow reconfiguration. Is there perhaps some other approach we can take to reduce the used up memory?

Comment: Use Query Store to identify queries with high memory grants or high memory consumption (https://matthewmcgiffen.com/2019/07/31/find-queries-with-high-memory-grants-using-query-store/), avoid scans on big tables by creating proper indexes, verify on the Performance blade of your Azure SQL database (Azure Portal) if there are queries using large amounts of RAM. These are some steps to start troubleshooting this.

Comment: We’re considering changing the elastic pool from general purpose to hyper scale with less vCores. Would this address the issue?

Comment: I honestly recommend DTU model to my clients. With DTU model I get the same configuration as a vCore for half the price. One of my customers told me I have saved  his company 2,500 dollars per month on a single Production database since 2018, I just put that database on DTU model at that time. Just make the math. I found vCore and Hyperscale very expensive. With vCore you pay licenses, with DTU you don't pay for that.